# Kotlin version error even though not related version in the project

Tags: android, kotlin

I am facing the following error in android project

> Could not find kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.72/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.72.jar

But my kotlin version is different in this project

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.20"
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

### module build

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
```

}

How to solve this error

Comment: post your module build.gradle also

Comment: try this     ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'

Comment: @Wini I tried with kotlin version 1.3.61. After downloading the dependencies it shows the same error `Could not find kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72)`

Comment: did you tried including this `implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"`? because it shows error related to jdk

Comment: tried that also. Getting same error